# dnx ef migrations --OutputDir usage

Tags: entity-framework-core

I wanted to add my EF7 migrations to a folder other than the root of Migrations. Ideally a context directory under Migrations but I can't even specify another root folder. The --outputDir seems to be what I want but I get the error 'unrecognized command or argument'. Any ideas on the correct usage?

Command I tried:

`dnx ef migrations add InitialMigration --outputDir MyContext --context MyContext`

Comment: This is a bug in EF. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug has been fixed in the EF nightlys. (NB the syntax changed slightly to `--output-dir`).